# IE 11 not displaying report parameter window for crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

We have noticed that IE 11 is not displaying the input parameter window where user inputs their parameters like date ranges or other parameters. While parameter windows shows up in firefox.

We are using crystal reports 2011 on tomcat 7 production servers.

Does someone have a fix for that or any input on what can I do to fix the problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

check whether Pop-up Blocker is on or not in IE 11.

Comment: Hi, the parameter window is a separate page and not a popup.

Comment: By separate page you mean a separate window? a pop-up is a separate window as well. So check if pop is turned on or off and get back on that. Thanks